# How many sig figs should go after this calculation?

Tags: significant-figures

> How many significant figures should be reported in the answer to the calculation (Assume all numbers are experimentally determined).
>
> $\frac{12.501 \times 3.52}{0.0042}+6.044$

I tried to do this problem as follows:

$12.501 \times 3.52 = 44.0$ (three sig figs because $3.52$)

Then, $\frac{44.0}{0.0042} = 1.0 \times 10^4$ (two sig figs because $0.0042$)

Finally, $1.0 \times 10^4 + 6.044 = 10006$ (no points past the decimal)

I think the answer is **5** because $10006$ has 5 sig figs. However, the correct answer is 2. Can someone please help me find out where I'm wrong?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about chemistry.

Comment: @Mithoron - Really? Significant figures are discussed in every beginning chemistry class.

Comment: @MaxW How said only chemistry is discussed in such classes? Chemistry students have classes about physics, mathematics, even some statistics. Sig figs may be useful in chem. but so is standard deviation and integrals and have as much sense to be asked here.

Comment: I'm totally with @MaxW here. We're way too trigger happy with marking stuff as not chemistry. Significant figures aren't even the correct way to measure errors. I've only ever had the chemists insist on using them.

Comment: @Mithoron I fully disagree. Insofar as the integral is about chemistry, it should be asked here and be expected to be answered here. What's next? We're going to insist quantum mechanics and statistical mechanics are just physics and applied math? Are those off-topic? Part of learning chemistry is learning to use the correct tools in the correct way. Please reconsider your position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addition follows the rule of keeping the greater of the least significant digits.

You have $\underline{10}000 + \underline{6.044}$ (underlines are significant). The largest least significant digit is the thousands place. Therefore, your final answer should be rounded to $1.0 \times 10^{4}$.

Another way to look at it is to consider an error of $\pm 1$ in the least significant digit of each addend:

$1.0\pm 0.1 \times 10^{4} + 6.044 \pm 0.001$

The largest answer you can obtain is $11006.045$ and the smallest number you can obtain is $9006.043$.

These correspond to the raw sum plus the summed uncertainties: $10006.044\pm 1000.001$. The most significant digit in the error (thousands) tells you which digit you are uncertain about, so that's the last significant figure in your answer.

Comment: how is the zero after the one a significant figure?

Comment: Because $1.0\times 10^{4}$.

Comment: I noticed the question had a significant zero.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, given the expression:

$$\dfrac{12.501 \times 3.52}{0.0042}+6.044$$

the desired is to find the answer with the correct number of significant figures.

(1) Be careful when rounding intermediate calculations. That can lead to a greater overall roundoff error.

(2) Let's look at the first part

$$\dfrac{12.501 \times 3.52}{0.0042}$$

- 12.5011 has 5 significant figures
- 3.52 has 3 significant figures
- 0.0042 has 2 significant figures

Since the term only has multiplication and division, the result of this part of this term should not have more than two significant figures. Generally I like to carry two extra significant figures in the intermediate calculation. No problem with modern calculators, but you can only get 3 digits with a slide rule, and 4 digits are pretty much the limit for even a good set of log tables. In this case, I'd use 5 digits for the intermediate result.

$$\dfrac{12.501 \times 3.52}{0.0042} = 10477.$$

(3) 6.044 has four significant figures.

(4) Now the question is what to do with the addition. 10477 is only really good to the thousands place, thus 6.044 is insignificant and the final result is $1.0\times10^4$

(5) Notice however if the first term had evaluated to $0.010477$, then the result would have been $6.054$ which has 4 significant figures.